# Evaluating two functions according to their performance

Tags: javascript

```js
        //Function-A
        function duplicatesNumber(text) {
            var counts = {};
            let textLowered = text.toLowerCase();
            textLowered.split("").forEach(function (x) {
                counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0) + 1;
            });
            return Object.entries(counts).filter(arr => arr[1] > 1).length
        }

        //Function-B
        function duplicateCount(text) {
            return text.toLowerCase().split('').filter(function (val, i, arr) {
                return arr.indexOf(val) !== i && arr.lastIndexOf(val) === i;
            }).length;
        }
       
       //Function-B
         let start = performance.now();
        console.log(duplicateCount("aaBBcDDcefgheeaas"))
        let end = performance.now();
        console.log("Function-B: "+ (end-start));
     
         
        
         //Function-A
         let start1 = performance.now();
        console.log(duplicatesNumber("aaBBcDDcefgheeaas"))
        let end1 = performance.now();
        console.log("Function-A: "+ (end1-start1))
```

- I have two functions they both do the same thing. Return the number of duplicates.
- My question is about their performances. I have just started to learn data structures and algorithms in javascript. I covered Big O'Notation. But I didn't get it correctly I guess.
- Since Function-A has for each method which means it is O(n) clearly. Isn't that mean Function-A should be slower than the second one? How can be Function-A is faster than Function-B?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Time Complexity

- Function A cost \$\mathcal{O}\left(n\right)\$

  - `toLowerCase`, `split` cost \$\mathcal{O}\left(n\right)\$
  - `forEach` cost \$\mathcal{O}\left(n\right)\$
  - `Object.entries`, `filter` cost \$\mathcal{O}\left(n\right)\$

    - `counts[x]` read / write may cost \$\mathcal{O}\left(1\right)\$ on average
- Function B cost cost \$\mathcal{O}\left(n^2\right)\$

  - `toLowerCase`, `split` still cost \$\mathcal{O}\left(n\right)\$
  - `filter` cost \$\mathcal{O}\left(n^2\right)\$

    - `indexOf`, `lastIndexOf` cost \$\mathcal{O}\left(n\right)\$
    - `filter` repeat above operation \$\mathcal{O}\left(n\right)\$ times, thus \$\mathcal{O}\left(n\cdot n\right)\$

Time consume most occurred in loops. Not only `forEach`, `fliter`, but also `toLowerCase`, `split`, `indexOf` are loops. You didn't count the performance of nested loops correctly.

Also, notice that big-O notation is targeted to describe how fast the time consume increase when size of input increase. It not necessarily means an algorithm with better big-O notation will always be faster.

### Implementation

- Do not use `str.split('')`, use `[...str]` if you can. The split one won't handle some unicode points correctly. For example, `[...'面'].length` is 3 but `'面'.split('').length` is 5.
- Use `Map` if you can (no need to support old browsers). `Object` is not an ideal way to use as a dictionary. Only if you want to keep ES5 support, you may use `Object.create(null)` instead.
- You may count how many entries has at least count 2 during iteration by tracking if `count[x] == 2` after increase. So there is no need to iterate `Object.entries` later.

Comment: Very clean and informative answer. I appreciate that!